# Internal process for launching a main entrypoint of a class

Tags: java, entry-point

I am curious about the whole process behind the `public static void main(args[])` launching in a Java class.

If some one could points me to **some classes involved in the JDK code source** ?

I want to know about the process in details.

I don't know where to start !

Comment: I'm looking for JDK internal source code which handle this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe here the `main` method is called (execution of `CallJavaMainInNewThread` method): [src/java.base/share/native/libjli/java.c Line 2361](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/38f0c08ee0fb7c50a6ecdb75e899b25a0ec2fb52/src/java.base/share/native/libjli/java.c#L2361)

`CallJavaMainInNewThread` declaration:
[src/java.base/share/native/libjli/java.h Line 161](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/673c732a333c6309ae7fb4ecdee5c0c0786a9665/src/java.base/share/native/libjli/java.h#L161)

`CallJavaMainInNewThread` implementations for particular platforms:

- Nix: [src/java.base/unix/native/libjli/java_md_solinux.c Line 741](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/673c732a333c6309ae7fb4ecdee5c0c0786a9665/src/java.base/unix/native/libjli/java_md_solinux.c#L741)
- MacOs: [src/java.base/macosx/native/libjli/java_md_macosx.m Line 739](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/79ed5ba4927a40905742af03c5808e533094ab30/src/java.base/macosx/native/libjli/java_md_macosx.m#L739)
- Windows: [src/java.base/windows/native/libjli/java_md.c Line 719](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/ce7ede95eb1c3ad99d4654bdcbc2574013461bd3/src/java.base/windows/native/libjli/java_md.c#L719)

OpenJDK source code repository: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/

Comment: Great buddy! Thats the exact starter thing i needed